# Can someone explain what went wrong with my code?

Tags: php, html

Here's my code

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Id</td>
                                    <td>Articles Category</td>
                                    <td>Update</td>
                                    <td>Delete</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <?php
                                        $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "whatever");

        $sql = "SELECT id_kategori, nama_kategori FROM kategori";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $cat);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo "<td>$id</td>";
            echo "<td>$cat</td>";
            echo "<td>Update</td>";
            echo "<td>Delete</td>";
        }
        $stmt->close();
                                    ?>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

The result is showing me this

> "prepare($sql); $stmt->execute(); $stmt->bind_result($id, $cat); while($stmt->fetch()) { echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; } $stmt->close(); ?> "

I change it to Object Oriented like this

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Id</td>
                                    <td>Articles Category</td>
                                    <td>Update</td>
                                    <td>Delete</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <?php 
                                        include 'connection.php'; 
                                        $showall = new connection(); 
                                        $showall->category(); 
                                    ?>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

My result is just this

> category(); ?>

Can someone explain what went wrong with my code ?

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with the syntax. But, mixing your PHP logic right inside the table is just bad!! Also, you didn't make anything OOP.

Comment: Looks like the short closing tag in your php configuration is set to just `>` or `->`. So php interpretation is stopped when that sequence appears in the code. You want to change that configuration to `?>`. It might also be that this effect appears when some layer inbetween your actual code and its rendering interprets the code, like some view sanitizer or similar, so a part of your framework.

Comment: Is my code working on yours ? or is it really my configuration "?>" problem ? I haven't change my xampp config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have used very bad coding standards.You just write db connection in the middle of HTML?. Okay You can write you HTML as

```
echo '<div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Id</td>
                                    <td>Articles Category</td>
                                    <td>Update</td>
                                    <td>Delete</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>';
                                    <?php
                                        $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "whatever");

        $sql = "SELECT id_kategori, nama_kategori FROM kategori";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $cat);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo "<td>$id</td>";
            echo "<td>$cat</td>";
            echo "<td>Update</td>";
            echo "<td>Delete</td>";
        }
        $stmt->close();
                                    ?>
                                echo '</tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>';
```

Comment: This is not much better. If you want to espouse good style then why not put  all the PHP at the top of the file, and then leave the HTML as plain HTML at the bottom and just echo  the variables as needed, i.e. `<?= $id ?>` ? Even better, put the HTML in a separate file and then include it.

Comment: Thnx, I know my code weird. But can I ask one more thing ?

Is it bad if i call html page from php, then from that html I call another php file ?

I call code above from this php.

<?php 
 include 'html/head.html';
 include 'html/nav.html';
 include 'html/article.html';
 include 'html/footer.html';
?>

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen yes that's coding practice ... user2977799 .. you need to practice good programming style rather just mixing any PHP code anywhere...

Comment: @user2977799 yes you can include html code inside php file and then include any other php file inside current file..But practice including php file at the top of the page and not anywhere..

Comment: Seems like It's my ajax load the one at fault here...

Without it, it works good.

Thnx for the explanation though, yeah that's true my code standard is pretty bad. I need to put php logic above then just call the result below :( thnx for the explanation :)